# "A measure whose domain includes all subsets of null sets is called complete"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I took this sentence from Folland's Real Analysis book. However, the "domain" in the sentence looks pretty vague to me. Can someone help me formulate this statement into precise math language?

This is my own try, but I need someone to confirm it(because if definition goes, then everything goes wrong):

A measure is called complete if $\mu(E)=0, F\subset E, F\in \mathcal{M} \Rightarrow\mu(F)=0$

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: $\mu(E)=0, F\subset E \Rightarrow F\in \mathcal{M}, \mu(F)=0$.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. So, the "domain" is actually the sigma algebra in the measure space :D !

Answer (score 2):

With your notation, it means 
$$\mu(E) = 0, F \subset E \implies F \in \mathcal{M}$$

A measure is a function with domain $\mathcal{M}$. Does that make it clearer? Finite additivity will automatically imply that measurable subsets of null sets are null.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is not quite correct. You list $F \in \mathcal{M}$ as a condition to be satisfied, but it is in fact the conclusion. A measure $\mu$ is complete on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ if whenever $F \subset E$ with $\mu(E) = 0$, we have $F \in \mathcal{M}$. It then follows that $\mu(F) \leq \mu(E) = 0$ so $\mu(F) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry for a further question, if $F\in \mathcal{M}, \mu(E)=\mu(F)=0$, can we conclude that $F\subset E$, and which properties need we use? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $F \subset E$?

Comment: Yea, sorry, typo

Comment: Do you mean $F \subset E$ instead of $F \in E$ before $\mu(E) = \mu(F) = 0$?